# Developing InputMethod For Burmese :: Android

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-input-method, southeast-asian-languages

I am developing Burmese Input Method for android 4.0.
I am following the sample soft keyboard provided in API Demos.

Now My question is

In qwert.xml of sample soft keyboard.I got the following.

```
....
<Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyIcon="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
        <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
```

In above snippet `android:codes="113"`    113 is UTF-8 code for character q.

What I did is I replaced the android:codes with UTF-8 code for Burmese Characters.
I was expecting that burmese character will be displayed but it displayes blank space for all the characters.

I am stucked up.Googled but nothing found.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the Solution for It.
We have to supply DCP i.e Decimal Coded point in android:codes attribute.
rest all the things will fall in place.We can also use UTF8 but need to do R and D if developing for language otherthan latin.